# UISearchBar issues Xcode 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uisearchbar

I am having issues with my `UISearchBar` that I have implemented. My app will compile and run, but as soon as I hit the search bar to begin typing a word in, it crashes. Can anyone tell me if you see anything wrong with my syntax? It is suppose to go through the states that I have in my `NSArray`.

**`TableViewController.h`:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController <UISearchBarDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *results;

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;

@end
```

**`TableViewController.m`:**

```
#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface TableViewController ()

@end

@implementation TableViewController
{
NSArray *states;
}

- (NSMutableArray *)results
{
if (!_results)
{
    _results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
return _results;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

states = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Alabama", @"Georgia", @"Tennessee", @"Colorado", nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)searchThroughData
{
self.results = nil;

NSPredicate *resultsPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains [search] $@", self.searchBar.text];

self.results = [[states filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultsPredicate] mutableCopy];
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
[self searchThroughData];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if(tableView == self.tableView)
{
    return [states count];
}

else
{
    [self searchThroughData];
    return self.results.count;
}
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (!cell)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}

if(tableView == self.tableView)
{
    cell.textLabel.text = [states objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

else
{
    cell.textLabel.text = self.results[indexPath.row];
}

return cell;
}
```

I am fairly new to Objective-C, so sorry if this is a simple question that I should know the answer to.

Thanks

Comment: What's the complete error? Have you looked at the stack trace?

Comment: See http://raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: I posted complete error.. It looks similar to the link you posted

Comment: That's not the error message. Follow the tutorial I linked and come back here when you can provide more details. Or delete your question if you figure it out after going through that tutorial.

Comment: @javaGeek really, you should read that link. it is (very) basic knowledge for every iOS developer! it's not possible to give any advice, if you have no backtrace and no real error message.

Comment: I am in the process of reading it now

Comment: I have figured out my issue, thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line of your `- (void)searchThroughData` method sets the NSMutableArray to nil. This may be the problem.